# Better method of setting UITableView cell types for specific cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using the following code to set the type of cell required, depending on the indexPath. This is such a messy method and I'm sure it can be cleaned up in some way. Is it possible to:

1. Have an `if` statement check MULTIPLE `int` values for the indexPath? (For example, `if indexPath.row == 0 or 1 or 2 {`)
2. Use the if statement to ONLY set the cell identifier, and then only declare the value of the text labels after the `if` statement?

Or if anyone has any other ideas for ways to make it more practical, i'd really appreciate it.

Here's the code:

```
       if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "timeCell") as! FridayTableCell
        cell.dateLabel.text = tableViewData[indexPath.row].time
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 5 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "timeCell") as! FridayTableCell
        cell.dateLabel.text = tableViewData[indexPath.row].time
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 10 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "timeCell") as! FridayTableCell
        cell.dateLabel.text = tableViewData[indexPath.row].time
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 14 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "timeCell") as! FridayTableCell
        cell.dateLabel.text = tableViewData[indexPath.row].time
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 18 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "timeCell") as! FridayTableCell
        cell.dateLabel.text = tableViewData[indexPath.row].time
        return cell
    } else { //default
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "default") as! FridayTableCell
        cell.dateLabel.text = tableViewData[indexPath.row].time
        cell.nameLabel.text = tableViewData[indexPath.row].name

       return cell
    }
```

Comment: Consider using sections instead?

Comment: I had considered this, but I found rows worked better for my use case.

Comment: I can not imagine a section wouldn't be simpler...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `if/else` to:

```
if [0, 5, 10, 14, 18].contains(indexPath.row) {
    //timeCell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "timeCell") as! FridayTableCell
    cell.dateLabel.text = tableViewData[indexPath.row].time
    return cell
} else {
    // default
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "default") as! FridayTableCell
    cell.dateLabel.text = tableViewData[indexPath.row].time
    cell.nameLabel.text = tableViewData[indexPath.row].name

    return cell
}
```

Or use a `switch`:

```
switch indexPath.row {
case 0, 5, 10, 14, 18:
    //timeCell
default:
    // default
}
```

Comment: Exactly what  I needed, so simple but works perfectly.